Update Case Owner based on Account Team Member
I am trying to create a Salesforce flow that will update the case owner to an Account Team member based on that account team member's role.
The flow should trigger when:

when the case is created
check the Account Teams if there is a member with a "CSU" role on a related account of the case
Assign that account team member with the "CSU" role as the new case owner

This will be my first time creating a flow so I'm not exactly sure how to write this out. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

This is a simple three step process.

First, use Get Records to find the Account Team Member. Next, see if a record was returned. If so, we use the Update Records element to assign the new Owner.
